# Changing Scene to Aria

Tags: dramatist

I am using the `dramatist` package for a libretto.  I want to replace the word of the `\scene` command with the word Aria.  So, every time I place a `\scene` command I would get the word Aria with a number.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: `dramatist` is quite a specialized package and you'll not find many people accustomed to it. A small example of code will definitely help in finding a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you gave no MWE so I had to guess a little bit.

In the documentation of package `dramatist` (type `texdoc dramatist` on your terminal/console) you can see that `\scene` uses `\scenename`  you can simply rename with

```
\renewcommand{\scenename}{Aria} % <=====================================
```

So the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% This will print the name of the speaking actor in boldface
\renewcommand{\speaksfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\scenename}{Aria} % <=====================================


\begin{document}

\Character[Wilheim - a person]{Wilheim}{will} % define characters

\scene[]


\begin{drama}

\willspeaks Vivamus varius tellus et mi pretium elementum iaculis tellus semper. Donec semper iaculis ante, 
convallis convallis arcu laoreet vitae. Aliquam id leo ac eros ultrices rhoncus porta sed ipsum.

\end{drama}

\end{document}
```

gives you:

[image]